# How to use set_prop_cycle in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider this example that plots two figures:

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.gca().set_color_cycle(['black','red'])
x = linspace(0.,10.,100)
y1 = sin(x)
y2 = cos(x)
plt.plot(x,y1,x,y2)
plt.show()
```

that results in:

[image]

The result is fine, but I get this warning:

```
MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The set_color_cycle attribute was deprecated in version 1.5. Use set_prop_cycle instead.
  warnings.warn(message, mplDeprecation, stacklevel=1)
```

[Here](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/tutorials/intermediate/color_cycle.html) I tried to study an example but  I cannot understand it.

How can I use "set_prop_cycle" correctly? I tried:

```
plt.set_prop_cycle(['black','red'])
```

but it does not work. I get this error message:

```
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'set_prop_cycle'
```

Comment: The equivalent of the former `plt.gca().set_color_cycle(['black','red'])` in matplotlib 2.0 or higher is `plt.gca().set_prop_cycle("color", ['black','red'])` as seen in the duplicate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [color cycle](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/tutorials/intermediate/color_cycle.html) docs,  `set_prop_cycle()` can be applied to `plt.rc()` or to a `matplotlib.axes.Axes` object.

Here's one way to do it with an Axes object:

```
from cycler import cycler

# separate the figure and axis elements of plt
f, ax = plt.subplots()

cy = cycler('color', ['black', 'red'])
ax.set_prop_cycle(cy)
ax.plot(x,y1,x,y2)
```

[image: plot]

FWIW for something like this you might find Pandas reads more clearly:

```
data = {"x":x, "y1":y1, "y2":y2}
colors = ["black", "red"]

pd.DataFrame(data).set_index("x").plot(color=colors)
```

Comment: Could you please explain why we need to use "subplots"? and what is the role of "f, " in the code? I also do not understand what you mean by using "Axis".

Comment: `plt.subplots()` is a way of getting at the `Axes` object.  `f` is a conventional name for the `figure` element in a Pyplot object.  It isn't used explicitly in this code example.  You can't apply `set_prop_cycle()` directly to `plt`.  This approach is taken directly from the documentation.  I've added a link to the docs and a brief additional explanation.